# Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to request access to EXTERNAL_STORAGE through the react-native PermissionsAndroid API but I keep getting this error

"Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity"

I've included this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The the code below is what's triggering the error.

```
PermissionsAndroid.request('READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE', 
    {
    'title': 'Photos Permission',
    'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera so you can 
    take awesome pictures.'
    }
)
```

I've searched everywhere and tried so many different things to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting for permission directly using the `'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'` string. Instead you should request it as:

```
PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
    {
    'title': 'Photos Permission',
    'message': 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera so you can 
    take awesome pictures.'
    }
)
```

`PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS` object contains all the permissions which need to be requested as its properties.

Comment: I don't know if it is the case in this situation, but i got the same error using 
`PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. 
@Dani  Do you use `ParmissionsAndroid.request` with succes and no errors?

Comment: yeah! I followed the exact code given in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html except, I used `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` instead of `CAMERA`. Worked fine

Comment: Did you add the required permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: Hehe, I wonder what is causing the errors here. Maybe i will try to test it in some diffrent scenarios..

Comment: Hmm, I did not, I think it's going to be the first thing for me to try, thanks :)

Comment: you should add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: I tried again and now i used `react-native init` to create project, not `create-react-native-app` and the problem didn't appear.

Comment: I used `react-native init` too... Didn't knew you used create react native app